# Zendesk - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, json, zendesk

I'm using the recent tickets JSON feed in Zendesk with the following line of PHP:

`$data = curlWrap("/tickets/recent.json", null, "GET");`

When I use a `foreach` function as below, I get the error message "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".

`foreach ( $data->tickets as $ticket )`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this means that `$data->tickets` is not an array

Comment: What does `var_dump(is_array($data->tickets));` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be an array. You can use the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn it into an array, eg

```
$json = curlWrap("/tickets/recent.json", null, "GET");
$data = json_decode($data);
```

And then you can proceed with the foreach array.

Comment: Thanks, I actually already had a json_decode in the function, however there was a 'true' parameter in there which I had thought to be the parameter to convert this to an array. As soon as I removed this, the problem was resolved. Thanks again!